# How do you get a list of all class children in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I have a lot of classes, but for this question I'll simplify it a bit.

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

class C extends A {

}

class D extends C {

}
```

Now my question is: how do you get a list of (all, not only direct) children of a class? So, `A.getChildren()` would be `[B, C, D]` and `C.getChildren()` would be `[D]`. By the way, I'm only looking for pure JavaScript solutions.

Maybe this isn't even possible and I need to approach this from a whole different way, like registering every class in its parent class.

So, is there a simple function (written or just built-in) that could do this, and if it's not even possible, in what other way should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control over `A`'s constructor *and* if every class is instantiated at least once, then you can put a line in the constructor which adds the child class to a `Set`:

```js
const classes = new Set();
class A {
  constructor() {
    classes.add(this.constructor);
  }
}

class B extends A {

}

class C extends A {

}

class D extends C {

}
new B();
new B();
new C();
new D();
console.log([...classes]);
```